# Dynamicaly add or remove elements with livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

in `LiveWire` i try to add some value in existing array witch i defined that as a field into `component`, but when i want to add value in that, i have fresh data after doing this action in other word that cause of clear and setting new value, for example:

```php
class Students extends Component
{
    public $inputs = [];
    public $i = 1;

    public function add($i)
    {
        $i = $i + 1;
        $this->i = $i;
        array_push($this->inputs ,$i);
    }
 
    public function remove($i)
    {
        unset($this->inputs[$i]);
    }
}
```

```html
<p wire:click="add(1)" class="t-text-lg">
    ...
</p>
```

here when i call `add` function, `input` value is `2` always, each calling `add` function should be incremented.

output:

```php
array:1 [▼
  0 => 2
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `$i` is always going to be `2` because of your logic.

```html
wire:click="add(1)"
```

```php
public function add($i)
{
    $i = $i + 1;
    $this->i = $i;
    array_push($this->inputs ,$i);
}
```

Every time you click the `p` element, you send the value `1` to the `add` function which then just adds `1` and saves that as the new value for `$this->i`. If you check your `$inputs` array you'll see it fill with elements all with the value `2`.

```php
array:2 [▼
  0 => 2
  1 => 2
]
```

What you more likely want is:

```php
public function add($i)
{
    $this->i = $this->i + $i;
    array_push($this->inputs, $this->i);
}
```

Resulting in:

```php
array:2 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
]
```

Comment: how about this code? it doesn't work correctly `$this->productSizes[] = $this->productSizes + [str::random(10) => str::random(10)];` i want to add another selected values on previous array which i has that as property: `public array $productSizes=[];` or this code is another solution: `array_push($this->productSizes, [str::random(10) => str::random(10)]);`

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Seems to work OK [here](https://phpsandbox.io/n/autumn-mouse-pzbe-vkqna).

Comment: when i try to use that in `livewire` component to add some data on clicking on for example `div` like with my post, data couldn't appended into array and i have a fresh array always

Comment: @DolDurma There must be something else effecting your code as I can't reproduce that problem.

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68016216/keeping-array-reference-and-adding-something-into-that`

Answer (score 1):

```
public function add($i)
{
    $this->i = $this->i + $i;
    array_push($this->inputs ,$this->i);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't any change

Comment: no, because your code is updating parameter variable `$i`. So, if you call `add` with `1`, $i is always `2`. and you sent that to `$this->i`. so, it is always `2`.

Comment: The solution is to increase `$this->i`. So, `$this->i = $this->i + $i;` it is increasing that.

Comment: could you please help me on this topic? `https://stackoverflow.com/q/68016216/1830228`