# Keeping array reference and adding something into that

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

In my very simple `Laravel livewire` component i have an array and when i try to add another data into that by clicking on a simple for example `div` i get fresh array with the last inserted data into that and i cant keep this array reference to append something data into that

```html
<div wire:click="addNewSize"></div>
```

```php
class SellerStoreNewProductComponent extends Component
{
    public array $productSizes=[];
    
    //...

    public function addNewSize()
    {
        /* SOLUTION ONE */
        //$this->productSizes[] = $this->productSizes + [str::random(10) => str::random(10)];

        /* SOLUTION TWO */
        //$this->productSizes[][]=array_push($this->productSizes, [str::random(10) => str::random(10)]);

        /* SOLUTION THREE */
        //array_push($this->productSizes, [str::random(10) => str::random(10)]);

        dd($this->productSizes);
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: you mean you want to add a new key value added onto the existing array??

Comment: Your click handler is called `add` but I do not see an `add` function in your code.

Comment: @Peppermintology i'm so sorry, i updated post

Comment: @zahid hasan emon yes, i want to add new data into existing array

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `data` you're trying to add to your `$productSizes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to add a `key` `value` pair to an existing array, you most likely want to use [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) rather than [`array_push`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

`array_merge` combines two `arrays` into a single `array` whereas `array_push` adds elements to an existing `array`.

```php
public function addNewSize()
{
    $this->productSizes = array_merge(
        $this->productSizes, [Str::random(10) => Str::random(10)]
    );
}
```

Comment: not working, when i call multiple `addNewSize` method. i have fresh array without previous data, i want to add data into array with exiting data

Comment: @DolDurma Then you have an error in your code somewhere as that principle does work

Answer (score 0):

your current approaches will add a new index with new array data (previous value plus new value). so you just have to add new index to the array.

```
$this->productSizes['myKey'] = "myValue";
```